# python AttributeError:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'vtkPVPythonModule' paraview

Tags: python, python-import, paraview

I'm developing a CAD application with paraview using python *ProgrammableFilter*, everything works fine when I make `import vtk` but if I try `from paraview.simple import ..`. I always get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 22, in <module>
File "<string>", line 2, in RequestData
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ParaView 4.1.0.32b\lib\paraview-4.1\site-  packages\paraview\servermanager.py", line 2190, in find_module
  if vtkPVPythonModule.HasModule(fullname):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'vtkPVPythonModule'
```

I though maybe if I set the `PYTHONPATH` it was going to work but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not supposed to import `paraview.simple` in a `ProgrammableFilter`. You should never to that. The `paraview.simple` module is for client-side control scripting, while `ProgrammableFilter` is for data processing and executes on the 'server' (even when not connected to a remote server).

Comment: The problem only occurs in my PC, I have tried the same import call  from another PC (from a collegue who is working in the same project) and it works fine...

Comment: It may seem like it works fine, but it's *wrong* :). It's not designed for that and it should not be used that way. Trust me -- I wrote significant parts of that code. It's a big *no! no!*. A rule of thumbs is never import paraview.simple or paraview.servermanager in the `Programable Filter`.

Comment: So, my next logic question is: How could I create a Spline with control points? I have tried using vtkParametricSpline and vtkParametricFunctionSource and it works but Im not able to modify the points in the UI. Using SplineSource (from paraview.simple) you can show the widget and modify those control points.

Comment: why just not create the spline? (from the menu, the python shell or a macro). If you want to specify the initial points you can do it , see http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/paraview/2011-November/023403.html

Comment: A filter cannot internally create other filters that you can control from the UI. For such a case, you may want to not use the `Programmable Filter`, but instead use a `Python Macro` or just run the script from the *Python Shell*.